# How to bind a vertex buffer to a uniform array in Gfx-rs?

Tags: opengl, rust, glsl, shader, gfx

I am trying to pass a list of `Uniform`s to a vertex shader using gfx-rs. The data is defined as follows

```
gfx_defines! {
    vertex Vertex { ... }

    constant MyConst {
        valoo: i32 = "my_val",
    }

    pipeline pipe {
        my_const: gfx::ConstantBuffer<MyConst> = "my_const",
        vbuf: gfx::VertexBuffer<Vertex> = (),
        out: gfx::RenderTarget<ColorFormat> = "Target0",
    }
}
```

The vertex shader is as follows:

```
#version 150 core

struct MyConst
{
    uint my_val;
};

in vec2 a_Pos;
in vec3 a_Color;
uniform MyConst my_const[];
out vec4 v_Color;

void main() {
    MyConst cc = my_const[0];
    v_Color = vec4(a_Color, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(a_Pos, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

When I introduce the first line in `main()`, the application crashes with the error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: DescriptorInit(GlobalConstant("my_const[0].my_val", None))'
```

[Full code](https://gist.github.com/pontjho/5cf3dc02056d0691b0d963e0949edc58)

Comment: [To make Stack Overflow a useful resource for future visitors beyond of the context of your repository](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/155423), please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] in the question itself, in addition to the link to your repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to bind a vertex buffer to a uniform array [...]

In OpenGL a vertex buffer cannot be *"bound"* to a uniform array.

A vertex attribute can address a named vertex buffer object (stored in the state vector of the Vertex Array Object), but a uniform can't. See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification).

If you want to bind some kind of buffer to some kind of uniform, then you've to use a [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) which is available since OpenGL 3.1 respectively GLSL version 1.40.

Or you can use a [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object), where the last element of the buffer can be an array of variable size. SSBOs are available since OpenGL 4.3 (GLSL version 4.30) respectively by the extension [`ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object.txt).

e.g.:

```c
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer MyConst
{
    uint my_const[];
};
```

See also [Using Shader Storage Buffer Objects (SSBOs)](https://jonathansteyfkens.com/blog/rust/2018/08/19/compute-shaders.html)